# react-tag-autocomplete handling duplicate tags

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, autocomplete

I'm using **react-tag-autocomplete** [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tag-autocomplete).

Everything works well but when I try to remove duplicate values from custom input(triggered by allowNew) the duplicates are not removed.

Try inputting custom tags using enter or tab.

Here is an example on codesandbox

[image: Edit nice-ramanujan-brydo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `includes` method does not works for objects.

You could use `map` method for collecting the all names by passing a *callback* function as `argument`.

```
handleAddition(tag) {
    var names = this.state.tags.map(({name}) => name);
    if (!names.includes(tag.name)) {
        this.setState(state => ({ tags: [...state.tags, tag] }));
    }
}
```